# How to auto-load index.html in sub-directories with Apache 2

Tags: apache2

I'm having problem auto-loading index.html in sub-directories with Apache 2.  Auto-loading of index.html works fine for root directory.

You see, to make things generic, my web app is written such that each module resides in its own sub-directory.  Each folder has 3 files - index.html for the front end (contains html + javascript), index.php for the backend (contains php code to access database) and index.css for styling.

Hence, to access the various modules in the web app:

> [Overview module] -
> http://xyz.com/overview?id=1234567890
>
> [Details module] -
> http://xyz.com/details?id=1234567890

Without the auto-load mechanism for sub-directories, the above would not be possible.

I would appreciate any help.
Thanks much!

Comment: This question is better suited for serverfault.com

Comment: Try with `DirectoryIndex index.html` in your httpd.conf. Also check the [mod_dir](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.3/mod/mod_dir.html) documentation.

Comment: @Suroot Thanks, will post administrative questions to serverfault.com in the future.  I posted here because most coders have to administer their development environment one time or another and I thought someone might have encountered this issue before.

Comment: @jweyrich Interestingly, the default 'DirectoryIndex' (not enclosed in any tag) in the httpd.conf didn't work for me.  I googled for quite a while and realized it didn't work for others as well.  However, if you create another DirectoryIndex under the <Directory 'htdocs'>, where 'htdocs' is your web root, it works.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Finally resolved it with a colleague.

The default DirectoryIndex specified in httpd.conf didn't work for us.
 Even though our sequence is 'index.html' then 'index.php', Apache2
will serve out 'index.php' first.  Only when 'index.php' is not
present in the same folder, then 'index.html' is served out.

We found 2 ways to overcome that:

Assuming your doc root is '/var/www/html',

```
[Method 1]
1.  Add a .htaccess to the root directory of your web app (e.g. /var/www/html/myapp).
2.  Add the line 'DirectoryIndex index.html' to the .htaccess.
3.  In httpd.conf, set 'AllowOverride' to 'All' under <Directory '/var/www/html'>.
```

```
[Method 2]
1.  In httpd.conf, add 'DirectoryIndex index.html' under <Directory 'var/www/html'>.
(note: this 'DirectoryIndex' is different from the default DirectoryIndex that is 
not enclosed within any tag.)
```

Restart the web server.

Hope this can help someone.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can use the following line in your `.htaccess` file:

```
DirectoryIndex index.html
```

Works even if you don't control the server configuration (if you use Gitlab Pages for example).